# How to replace the delay() function in my code?

Tags: sensors, led, millis

I'm new to Arduino and I currently have a project that involves the control of an LED via ultrasonic sensor. Basically, if an object passes through the ultrasonic sensor, the LED will be ON for 5 seconds but adding another set of LED and ultrasonic sensor with the same function gives a problem because the other LED won't light up if the other one is ON and vice versa because of the delay whereas what I want is to be able to make them both light up and stay lit for 5 seconds after their respective ultrasonic sensors detect an object. I've tried using the "Blink without delay" example but I can't understand it nor make it work. Please help me guys and thanks for reading. Here is my current code:

```
int trigPin1=2;
int echoPin1=3;

int trigPin2=4;
int echoPin2=5;

int led1=10;
int led2=11;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);

  pinMode(led1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  long duration1, distance1;
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
  distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance1 >= 500 || distance1 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print ( "Sensor1  ");
    Serial.print ( distance1);
    Serial.println("cm");
       }

  long duration2, distance2;
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(echoPin2, HIGH);
  distance2= (duration2/2) / 29.1;

  if (distance2 >= 500 || distance2 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor2  ");
    Serial.print(distance2);
    Serial.println("cm");       
       }




  if(distance1>20 || distance2>20){
    digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
  }
  else if(distance1<20){
    digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
  }

  else if(distance2<20){
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of delaymicroseconds for measuring is fine.

you'll want to replace the `delay(5000)` when switching the leds.

```
  if(distance1>20 || distance2>20){
    digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
  }
  else if(distance1<20){
    digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
  }

  else if(distance2<20){
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
  }
```

you can do that by using a timestamp of when the distance was last high:

```
  if(distance1<20){
    digitalWrite(led1,HIGH);
    timestamp1 = millis();
  }

  if(distance2<20){
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    timestamp2 = millis();
  }

if(millis() - timestamp1 > 5000){
  digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
}

if(millis() - timestamp2 > 5000){
  digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
}
```

`timestamp1` and `timestamp2` should be globals (or static locals). This code will delay turning off the led to 5 seconds after the sensor last detected something close.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to do it using your hints but I believe the code after if(millis()-timestamp1>5000) should be digitalWrite(led1,LOW);

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge indeed they should be set to low there. copy paste errors...